# Bluetooth connection in Android with two devices

Tags: bluetooth

I just wondered if it is possible to connect more than one device in the same time through bluetooth. I mean one device want to share some info with other two devices in the same time is it possible through bluetooth or not? (I have 2 Nexus 5 one Nexus 7) .

This is my initiator:

```
    if(requestCode ==  REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE){
        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the device MAC address
            ArrayList<String> address = data.getExtras().getStringArrayList(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address.get(0));
            BluetoothDevice device2 = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address.get(1));
            ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices=new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            devices.add(device);
            devices.add(device2);
            // Attempt to connect to the device
            mChatService.connect(devices);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my bluetooth chat service:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class BluetoothChatService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BluetoothChatMulti";

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceAddresses;
    private ArrayList<ConnectedThread> mConnThreads;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothSocket> mSockets;
    private boolean bothConnected=false;
    /**
     * A bluetooth piconet can support up to 7 connections. This array holds 7 unique UUIDs.
     * When attempting to make a connection, the UUID on the client must match one that the server
     * is listening for. When accepting incoming connections server listens for all 7 UUIDs. 
     * When trying to form an outgoing connection, the client tries each UUID one at a time. 
     */
    private ArrayList<UUID> mUuids;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     * @param context  The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
        mDeviceAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        mConnThreads = new ArrayList<ConnectedThread>();
        mSockets = new ArrayList<BluetoothSocket>();
        mUuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();
        // 7 randomly-generated UUIDs. These must match on both server and client.
        mUuids.add(UUID.fromString("b7746a40-c758-4868-aa19-7ac6b3475dfc"));
        mUuids.add(UUID.fromString("2d64189d-5a2c-4511-a074-77f199fd0834"));

    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(InitiatorActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state. */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mAcceptThread == null) {
            mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mAcceptThread.start();
        }
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices) {


        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
     /*   if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
*/
        // Create a new thread and attempt to connect to each UUID one-by-one.    
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try {
                mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(devices.get(i), mUuids.get(i));
                mConnectThread.start();


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }


    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");

        //Commented out all the cancellations of existing threads, since we want multiple connections.
        /*
        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
         */

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
        // Add each connected thread to an array
        mConnThreads.add(mConnectedThread);

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(InitiatorActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(InitiatorActivity.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // When writing, try to write out to all connected threads 
        for (int i = 0; i < mConnThreads.size(); i++) {
            try {
                // Create temporary object
                ConnectedThread r;
                // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
                    r = mConnThreads.get(i);
                }
                // Perform the write unsynchronized
                r.write(out);
            } catch (Exception e) {             
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
        // Commented out, because when trying to connect to all 7 UUIDs, failures will occur
        // for each that was tried and unsuccessful, resulting in multiple failure toasts.

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(InitiatorActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(InitiatorActivity.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(InitiatorActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(InitiatorActivity.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        public AcceptThread() {
        }

        public void run() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            try {
                // Listen for all 7 UUIDs
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    serverSocket = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, mUuids.get(i));
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    if (socket != null) {
                        String address = socket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress();
                        mSockets.add(socket);
                        mDeviceAddresses.add(address);
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                    }                       
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
            }
            if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private UUID tempUuid;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuidToTry) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            tempUuid = uuidToTry;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);    
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            setName("ConnectThread");

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (tempUuid.toString().contentEquals(mUuids.get(1).toString())) {
                    connectionFailed();
                }
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(InitiatorActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(InitiatorActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth on Android allows more than 1 device to be connected at once. The limits have to do with the bluetooth radio channels and any higher level protocol being used (e.g. RFCOMM). In my SmartGear app, I connect 2 bluetooth game controllers (RFCOMM) at the same time and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. Could you provide a sample code? My app is not for commercial purpose. It is just for a scientific work.

Comment: Do you need sample code for general bluetooth connections in Android or specifically for the 2 connection case? In my case, I have 0, 1 or 2 controllers connected, so I spawn a new thread for each connection and it runs as long as the connection is alive. I'm not sure you would benefit from seeing my code unless you have a specific doubt that I can help with.

Comment: Hi yes I need something like that. It is about secure multipart computation. I have general blueetooh connections it is perfectly working. I need to provide connection between three devices A-B A-C B-C

Comment: If you've already got connections working, then the only missing piece is threads. You need to use:         new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
         public void run()
         {
                <your communication code here>
                }
          }).start();

Comment: I am trying to modify bluetoothchat sample.However i even couldnt succeed to provide multiple connection.

Comment: It would be best to see what you've tried...please post what you can.

Comment: I just post the code. Thank you so much. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth can not support multiple connection at a time.In android there is peer to peer connection.If u want to send same data to multiple device.for the resolution of this problem from bluetooth sample:

1.Getting all nearest device mac address from DevicelistActivity store in a collection or array.

2.Connect device one by one with the help of mac address of device.

3.When one device is connected and data sending is done after that terminate previous connection and new connection is established and connect another device.

4.Hope so this informaion might helpful for u.

Comment: Hi thank you for answer :) I finished it before summer ;) but my solutions were the same ;)

Comment: @user12492 if u satisfy from my answer please up vote my answer.